# C++ 2D array reading

Tags: c++, arrays, function, 2d

I need some help. I need to make a modular program. But I have a little trouble. So, I need to read a 2D array but user defines row and column. 
After the reading I need to make some calculations in another functions... but i can't write well a function which works...
I have tried with pointers... but I can't use well. I'm beginner.

```
//main
int a[2500]; //symbolic. n<=50 -in my case
int n;

reading (a*,n);
//reading function
void reading(int* array[], int &n)
{
    cout << "n=<<;
    cin >> n;

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < n ;j++) {
            cin >> array[i][j];
        }
    }
}
```

Please help me.

Comment: You must describe the problem you are facing. Is it a compilation error, a runtime error or some error in the program logic?

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of problems with this code. The most glaring one is that C++ != Python, so you have to put the main code inside a function like this:

```
int main() {
//Main code here, calling other functions etc
reading (&a,n);
return 0; //or return 1 to signal there has been an error
}
```

From there, you can work on your code. The good thing about a modular design is that you can debug parts of it and be sure each part works. Use a debugger, and ask a question with a single question in on SO if you are still stuck after doing some research too.

Answer (score 0):

i got a right solution ;)

```
 //main
int **matrix, n;
matrixread(matrix,n);


//matrixread 
void matrixread(int** &matrix, int &m)
{
cin >> m;
matrix = new int*[m];
for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
{
    matrix[i] = new int[m];
}
for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < m; j++)
    {
        cout << "matrix[" << i << "," << j << "]= " ;
        cin >> matrix[i][j];
    }
}
```